# Load a map with specific places acount as a reference without iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is there a way to load a map using js, but show the reference location as an actual places listing?

I'd like to load a map that shows a particular business (I have the places reference number) then display a map around it.

I would just use the iframe, but it doesn't allow for the level of customization that the js library does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is one of the more standard ways of using maps.

You have the lat long for the location to both center your map and drop a marker (probably a custom image of for instance the company logo).

Just follow any of the tutorials. They all show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a business that you have the reference number for then use the [`PlacesService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService).

You will also need to include the places library in the API url.

e.g

```
// I assume the map is already loaded and defined as variable called map
var placesService = new PlacesService();

placesService.getDetails({reference: placeReferenceNumber}, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: place.geometry.location
        });
        // Warning: Viewport may not always be defined
        map.setBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but the location just loads the name of the business on the map. I am trying to get the data similar to what shows up on google maps, ie. name, address, phone number, reviews, picture

Comment: @JustinEhlert Have a look at the place object properties. I only used the location in my example, but it has everything you need. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult)